# Get option text from html template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm developing a program, but i'm stuck currently, trying to get text from an option from my html. I've read a lot of posts lately about *plnkr*, but as i'm using electron and AngularJS, I'm not sure how to set it up.

Example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0BzvwOIQUdfS3KfKUtcS?p=preview

In the example, the result should be that the text of the selected option would be exported to a json when clicking on the OK button, but it's only exporting the value eg. **action: 1**

The exported **json atm**. looks like this:

```
{
  "keybindings": [
    {
      "keyString": "B",
      "action": "3",
      "shiftKey": true
    }
  ]
}
```

but I'm trying to get

```
{
  "keybindings": [
    {
      "keyString": "B",
      "action": "eraser_tool_action",
      "shiftKey": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I've shortened the code, but there's supposed to be 81 options.

Here's the code for the **template**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head ng-app="app">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
  <form class="modal-content">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Key</label>
    <select for="entry" class="form-control" ng-model="entry.actionEvent" onchange="CheckDesc(this.value);">
      <option value="0">-- choose an action --</option>
      <option value="1"  ng-model="entry.actionEvent">eraser_tool_actionEvent</option>
      <option value="81"  ng-model="entry.actionEvent" >decrease_brush_size_actionEvent</option>
    </select>
    <div class="form-action">
      <button type="button" ng-click="close()" id="cancel-entrywindow" class="btn btn-form btn-default">Close</button>
      <button type="button" ng-click="addEntry(entry)" class="btn btn-form btn-primary">OK</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here's the **script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('controllers', ['angularModalService']);
app.controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams){
    $scope.entries = db('keybindings').cloneDeep();

    $scope.removeEntry = function(entry){
      var query = {keyString: entry.keystring, action: entry.actionEvent, shiftKey: entry.modifier1, ctrlKey: entry.modifier2, altKey: entry.modifier3};
      db('keybindings').remove(query);
      $scope.entries = db('keybindings').cloneDeep();
    };
  }
]);

app.controller('EntryCtrl', ['$scope', 'close', '$routeParams', '$location',
  function($scope, close, $routeParams, $location){
    $scope.entry = {
      'keyString': '',
      'action': '',
      "shiftKey": false,
      "ctrlKey": false,
      "altKey": false
    };

    $scope.addEntry = function(entry){
      var t = $scope.entry;
      alert('works');
      var data = {keyString: t.keystring, action: t.actionEvent, shiftKey: t.modifier1, ctrlKey: t.modifier2, altKey: t.modifier3};
      if(data === null)
      {
          alert('Insert something');
      }
      else{
          db('keybindings').push(data);
      }
      $location.path("/");
    };

    $scope.close = close;
}

]);

app.controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope, ModalService) {
    $scope.showModal = function() {
        ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: 'addentry.html',
            controller: "EntryCtrl"
        }).then(function(modal) {
            modal.element.modal();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-model` shouldn't be there on `options` element, also don't use `onchange` function, which isn't needed either. Better do have it implemented in angular way by having `options` array in controller & then use `ng-options` directive to render out select dropdown.

```
<select for="entry" class="form-control" ng-model="entry.actionEvent" 
 ng-options="option.id as option.value for option in options">
  <option value="0">-- choose an action --</option>
</select>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KX7l89T5eIEULkAdFVxT?p=preview)

**Code**

```
$scope.options = [
   {id: 1, value: 'eraser_tool_actionEvent'},
   {id: 81, value: 'decrease_brush_size_actionEvent'},
]
```

Comment: Mhh okay, but isn't there a way to do it without putting all my values into the scope? it's terribly long atm... The onchange function is needed, as i'm comparing two values against each other further down the html(which is not showed) to compare the value against another value from another script.

Comment: Okay so I figured it out, I modified your answer a bit, but since it was a matter of getting the right variable.. I'll give you the mark for it ;) http://plnkr.co/edit/ACEUnvtu0EXdehoM6sle?p=info - I ended up doing it in the .js file anyway.. I thought it wouldn't work, but it does so thanks.